# Swift Animation - Splash screen logo to slide up into logo on login screen

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am an animation noob, but I found a really great transition animation. The Discover mobile app on iOS has their logo centered on the splash screen. The logo then slides up and scales down a bit and the login screen slowly appears during the animation. I have a start and end position for my logo, and I know the sizes I need it to start with and end with. I am not sure how to animate it sliding up and revealing the login screen.

Comment: Shameless plug but I wrote this: https://github.com/pbush25/LDSplashView it hasn't been updated in awhile but unless you've already moved to Swift 3 it should still work. Feel free to PR it if you wanted to update it! :p

Comment: I'll take a look, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the `logo` first to appear centered you should use `NSLayoutConstraints`.

Create a `ViewController` that looks like your `LaunchScreen` and set a `@IBOutlet` connection to your logo's `size` and `position`, and to your `loginView`. The simple perform something like:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) 
{
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   self.logoHeightFromTopConstraint.constant = 100
   self.logoWidthConstraint.constant = 80
   self.loginView.alpha = 0.0

   UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations:
   {
       self.loginView.alpha = 1.0
       self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
   })
}
```

You might have to remove/add some `NSLayoutConstraints` to achieve what you want, but this is the general idea.

Comment: Aerows, thanks for getting me started. I was having some issues trying to animate to a constraint. I was trying to get my logo to go to the same position across all devices. Is this possible?

Comment: Depends what you mean with same position, what behaviour are you expecting?

Comment: On my login screen I have my logo set with an constraint with 75 away from the top of screen. This looks great on iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. I did some playing around with animation and when I put in a value that the animated logo should end on, it looks great on one device and not another. I was wanting to find a way to animate a logo to a certain x/y plot, regardless of screen.

Comment: I forgot to add I am creating the view and constraints programmatically from AppDelegate

Comment: `NSLayoutConstraints` are made so they can look good on every device. A straightforward way to do this would be to find a set of `constraints` for the start and the finish of your animation, replace the constraints and then animate `layoutIfNeeded`. 
I would strongly suggest using `InterfaceBuilder` for this though, as you can make use of [Size Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/BuildingforMultipleScreenSizes.html), which further simplifies design for different devices.